# Error showing url: Error when getting information for file when gnome-open

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome, pdf, gnome-open

For some reason I can't open this pdf file with gnome-open command.

```
cd /media/c-drive/Users/Tommy/Desktop/JobEssays/
gnome-open "./My\ Resume.pdf"
```

I get this error.

```
Error showing url: Error when getting information for file '/media/c-drive/Users/Tommy/Desktop/JobEssays/My\ Resume.pdf': No such file or directory
```

My default document viewer is "Document Viewer"

Edit: I get "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: " when removing the quotes or backslash from gnome-open.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either remove the quotes or remove the backslash.  You can use either/or but not both when specifying a file.

When you use the quotes you are telling the system, in this case, that the backslash is part of the file name.  If you didn't use quote, the backslash would function as an escape character that would prevent the space in the filename from being separated as multiple words.

Comment: I get "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: " when removing the quotes or backslash.

Comment: @TommySaechao What command did you use to connect to the computer.  Most likely you used, `ssh`.  Try logging to the computer using `ssh -X`.

Comment: I am directly running Ubuntu through an installation onto my hard drive.

Comment: @TommySaechao gnome-open is a tool to call on the system's X default program to open a source.  In this case your source is a `pdf`.  If your X environment is working, you can just open up the directory from `Nautilus` and double click on the file.  You can also try a different cli for the file... what do you get when you use `xdg-open` instead of `gnome-open`?